# How could I have provided a better code sample for my Spring queston

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I asked a [Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62119488/how-can-i-disable-authentication-for-a-specific-endpoint/62125656#62125656) question yesterday. I included the code for the relevant components, but no one was able to help me until some wonderful user asked to see the full code on GitHub in chat, and realized that the problem was due to how my packages were arranged in their packages.

How could I have done better at included all the relevant details in my question?

Obviously, just posting the GitHub link is not correct.

In hindsight, provided information about the package structure would have helped, but then if I had suspected that was relevant I would (I hope) have been able to solve my own problem.

How could it have been better?

Comment: Create a [mcve] for your problem i.e. a Spring boot application that has **only** the necessary lines of code and structure to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: @RobertLongson So you're saying you want want the entire minimal application posted into the question?

Comment: Well you might well have realised what the issue was yourself once you did that and then you'd not have posted a question at all or alternatively you'd know enough about what to search for to find an existing Q&A.

Comment: Yes, that. I solve 90% of my issues while trying to reduce my code to the smallest sample that still fails.